# Datatables format data output

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

i m using datatables w/ server-side processing, everything work perfect, but i dont know how i can use a php function on data output.

i have this code

```
$('#exampless').dataTable({

  "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,

    "sAjaxSource": "data/load-anunciantes.php",     

     "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -2,
        "data": 7, // STATUS 1 or 0

    } ]



} );
```

the column 7 return 1 or 0 its fine but i want to do something like this.

on php i was doing

```
status($status);
```

if status = 1 i return `<label class=\"green\">Active</label>` and

if status = 0 i return `<label class=\"red\">Inactive</label>`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `render` or `mRender` (depending on which version of datatables you're using):

```
"columnDefs": [ {
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
    if(row[7] == 1){
        return '<label class=\'green\'>Active</label>';
    }else{
       return '<label class=\'red\'>Inactive</label>';
    }
 },
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, i was going on this solution i found http://andersontorres.com.br/hacks-e-outras-coisas/manipulando-tabelas-com-o-datatables/  thanks